# How do I show div when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my CSS code. I want to set the display so that my text whats in the div shows up.

```
div.divi
{display: none}
```

This is my HTML code.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <title>Over informatica en ik</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="opmaak.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="divi">
        <p class="groot">Informatica</p>
        <p>hoi</p>
        </div>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementByClass('divi').style.display ='block'">
</button>


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) What are you trying to do? Hide and show the div with JavaScript?

Comment: `divi` is a class...not an ID. I'd start there,

Comment: Yeah i editied that :), i want if i click on my button, my text what's in the div shows up

Comment: ``getElementByClass`` should be ``getElementByClassName``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
div.divi {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="divi">
  <p class="groot">Informatica</p>
  <p>hoi</p>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('divi')[0].style.display ='block'; this.style.display = 'none';">
</button>
```

Tell me if it needs improvement :)

Comment: It worked :), is there also a code that the button will remove :)

Comment: @RyonM Are you saying that you want to hide the text again or do you want the one button to serve both actions (toggle)?

Comment: I want if i clicked on the button, that the button will be removed.

Comment: @RyonM You want the button to be hidden when clicked too? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes :) exactly that :)

Comment: @RyonM Updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `<div class="divi">` with `<div id="divi">` and the CSS with `div#divi{display: none}`.

Or if you would prefer to keep `divi` as a class instead of an ID, you can update your code to the following:

```
<div class="divi">
    <button id="div3">
      <p class="groot">Informatica</p>
      <p>hoi</p>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('divi')[0].style.display='block'">Text</button>
```